# How can I synchronize and backup a large number of git repositories?

Tags: git

I have a number of git repositories which I would like to keep synchronized and backed up.  By synchronized, I mean that I work off of several different computers and want to always use the latest copy.  By backup, I would like to have something that I can restore from quickly (less than 5 minutes).

The options I see are:

1. consolidate to a single repository

   not a problem now, but perhaps down the road when I want to only share a subset of code
   just run git push/pull once
2. write a script to recurse into sub-directories and run git push/pull

   a bunch of git sub-modules is a pain to manage, is there any other way to do this without having to recurse through all the sub-modules.

Comment: Your operating system is... ? (or does it even matter?)

Answer (score 0):

If those repos aren't too big, another solution would be to recurse into sub-directories and run [**`git bundle --all`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251713/backup-of-github-repo/1251717#1251717):

You ends up with *one* file per repo, much easier to save/transfert.

From each bundle, you can easily pull/clone in order to restore a working Git repo.